# Angular UI-Router: Accept same query parameter on every url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm curious if there's a way to configure UI-Router to accept a query string parameter for all routes in an application.

For context, I have a `resolve` handler on all of my application's routes, which takes in a query parameter and triggers some behaviour based on that parameter. Here's a reduced version of my application's state definitions:

```js
$stateProvider
  .state('state1', {
    url: '/state1?myparam'
    resolve: myHandler,
    templateUrl: 'state1.html',
    controller: 'Ctrl1',
  })
  .state('state2', {
    url: '/state2?myparam',
    resolve: myHandler,
    // [etc]
  })
  .state('state2.child1', {
    url: '/state2/child1?myparam',
    resolve: myHandler,
    // [etc]
  })
  // [and a bunch more similar '.state's];
```

This works fine, and I'm able to access the `myparam` value inside of `myHandler` via `$stateParams`. It just seems a bit repetitive to add `?myparam` to every route definition's `url`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried using `$urlMatcherFactory`.

Snippet:

```
var urlMatcher = $urlMatcherFactory.compile("/state2/:id?param1");
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
    url: urlMatcher 
});
```

Hope this [query params](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#query-parameters) and [urlMatcherFactory file](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/src/urlMatcherFactory.js)helps you.

P.S: I did not test this code.

Comment: Thanks @Sagar, urlMatcherFactory looks promising - I didn't see that in the ui-router docs. I'll give it a try when I have a little time, and report back!